# Some object memebers not pushed to Firebase Realtime DB

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Realtime DB to save some data, among it I push a POJO named Offer. The Offer class has 9 members, but for some reason one of those members is not being inserted to the corresponding child in FB when I use push(). For other objects I push to Firebase I see no problem.

I should note that the object's members were changed, but other changed members are pushed successfully...

I also tried to push it after the whole object is pushed, using the updateChildren() method, but it didn't work.
Also Invalidated caches in case this is an android studio issue somehow, also didn't help.

I tried changing the path in firebase which I upload to, but the behavior remained the same.

Pushing the object is done pretty straight forward:

```
final Offer n_offer = createOfferObjectFromView();
mOffersDatabaseReference.push().setValue(n_offer, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() { ... }
```

Offer looks likes this:

```
public class Offer implements Parcelable {
    private String      title;
    private String      photoUrl;
    private Integer     quantity;
    private Float       origPrice;
    private Integer     discount;
    private String      s_time;
    private String      e_time;
    private boolean     active;
    private String      fbKey; 
...
}
```

But pushed to Realtime DB like that:
https://i.ibb.co/tZhjg0b/Untitled.png

As you can see, the s_time member is missing.
What could go wrong?

Comment: Did you assigned any value to s_time? Because you are using `Parcelable`. And assigned then can we see your code of `Offer` class?

Comment: yes, s_time stores a valid string, I can see it in debug before pushing the Offer to the DB.

Comment: show us this debug info

Comment: When writing a Java object, Firebase will write any `public` fields, and public JavaBean properties (for which you define a `get...` or `set...`). Did you define a getter/setter for `s_time`?

Comment: No, and that solved it! Thanks a lot.